# Are there any way to livestream to youtube or facebook from Jitsi Meet without Jibri & Docker Lib Jitsi-meet?

Tags: http-live-streaming, youtube-livestreaming-api, jitsi, jitsi-meet, lib-jitsi-meet

Currently, we are trying to integrate the Livestream feature without the help of jibri & lib jitsi meet. Are there any possibilities by which we can Livestream to any social media without jibri.

Can somebody help me with this?

Are there any prerequisites for live streaming?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simply no (till today),I know jibri is costly but there is no prebuilt better solution which can do the work of jibri like conference recording or streaming.